# Entity Framework Migration Adding Column Twice

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, migration, entity-framework-migrations

I'm running Entity Freamework Code First Migrations.  When trying to run the application I get the error: A column ID occurred more than once in the specification.  I have AutomaticMigrationsEnabled set to true in the configuration because when I run the project, I want the migrations to run automatically.

This is the verbose results when I tried running it through the package manager:

Applying code-based migration: 201211261626569_AddActiveFlagForProjects.

```
ALTER TABLE [Projects] ADD [Active] [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
```

[Inserting migration history record]
Applying automatic migration: 201211261901371_AutomaticMigration.

```
ALTER TABLE [Projects] ADD [Active] [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
```

Why is EF trying to alter the projects table twice?

I'm using Entity Framework 5.0 and SQL CE 4.0.

Comment: any chance of seeing the project class and any classes it may be related to? It seems you are *adding* this property. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding -IgnoreChanges flag to Add-Migration

http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/652