# Entityframework Migrations Repair

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migration, entity-framework-migrations

i am using EF6 code first approach to create a database (SQL Compact Edition).  Furthermore i am using MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion as Migration strategy. Now i have following Problem, as my Software runs on multiple machines with different Versions (differnt EF Model Versions) the databases are not all the same (no big changes, just new columns in tables). Normally the Migration to latest version works perfect except in one database, i have no idea why. So i tried to delete the _migrationshistory manually and imported it from an existing db which works pretty fine. Now i was wondering if there is a programmatical way to "repair" a non working database (recreate _migrationshistory, migrate to latest version if possible).
I already tried the DbMigrator class but had no big success.

KR Manuel

Comment: You should not need to "repair" migrations. usually there is a problem, e.g.  the migration does not match the database's state (what EF thinks it needs to do). This may happen because of a manual schema change that conflicts with the DbMigrations content (e.g. Table already exists). Can you give more information(e.g. the error/exception) you got?

Comment: Depending on the situation, you might generate an [idempotent script](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#idempotent) which will give you a script of the complete history you could use to compare against the deployed database.

Comment: Hi Bernhard, i am receiving following error: "a column id occurred more than once in the specification". In my new model i added just one field. Most of my databases are migrating right some do not. When i copy the _migrationhistory table Content from a working database to a not working i do not receive the error.

Comment: Hi Manuel, sorry I did not see your comment. It's hard to say whats happengin, without seeing the existing DB Schema, Migration etc. But I would guess it that the _migrationhistory and the migrations do not match and EF wants to execute a migration that does not work in this scenario (the migrations should work . beter not manually modify the migrationshistory table). 
Maybe one of the following links is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571576/entity-framework-migration-adding-column-twice

Comment: or https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/e43da6d4-2b73-47a5-961c-50cef16c0cff/databaseschemaupdater-error-a-column-id-occurred-more-than-once-in-the-specification?forum=wpdevelop